# Authentication and Authorization on AKS microservices application

Tags: azure, authentication, authorization, microservices, azure-aks

I am working on a new project, we decided to have a Microservices design due to different backend heavy workloads and all the other benefits from this kind of architecture.

The application will be hosted as containers on **Azure AKS**, we also can have access to various Azure services in case needed (Azure AD, Storage Accounts, etc).

It will be in 3 tiers having:

- Frontend Webapp (AngularJS), the only container externally reachable
- Backend API in various containers (written in Python FastAPI and .NET)
- Database (Azure Postgres most probably)

My main concern right now is what should be the best way (more secure and convenient) to implement in the application **user Authentication** in first place, and eventually Authorization as well, in this kind of architecture.
I see many alternatives, also having access to Azure services, I don't know which is the most convenient one.

The idea is to have like SSO integrated with **Azure AD**, or kind of unique token session maintained (maybe with an API Gateway?) to access the Frontend webapp, which should be the only object that makes requests to the Backend microservices.

Or is it ok to integrate Azure AD in the Angular frontend, have JWT injected in backend requests there and just validate the JWT in the backend microservices? And eventually use it also to authorize users?

I was also checking oauth2-proxy (https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/) that seems cool but also a bit tricky to implement, maybe also a bit over-complicated since the only exposed container is the Frontend one.

Which are your best practices and suggestions for this kind of architecture?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you start with: we need only 1 services exposed, but you will end up with 5 or more :)

With that being said, I would recommend to use oauth2-proxy together with Azure AD. Its a common pattern we use a lot with customers on Azure.

It is also not very complicated, you just need an [App registration](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/oauth_provider/#azure-auth-provider), the oauth2-proxy [Helm Chart](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/manifests/tree/main/helm/oauth2-proxy) and the `client_id` & `client_secret` of your app registration & a random `cookie_secret` as secret inside Kubernetes (maybe use CSI Secrets Store with Azure Key Vault for this).

You then add annotations to your ingress resources :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://oauth.example.com/oauth2/start
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://oauth2-proxy.auth-namespace.svc.cluster.local/oauth2/auth
```

[Here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2021/06/how-to-use-oauth2-proxy-for-central-authentication/) is a complete workflow.